# Using iDB2Connection and handling locked jobs

Tags: .net, vb.net, db2, ibm-midrange

We have a .NET web service accessing our iSeries. If our web service calls a stored procedure that results in a halt (LCKW or MSGW), any subsequent calls to the web service timeout because we cannot open a new connection (the code below hangs at oConnection.Open). If the iSeries job is ended we solve the problem. My question is how to get the iDB2Connection object, on "Open", to not attempt to use the halted job and instead open a new one?

```
Using connection = New iDB2Connection("DataSource=DATASOURCE;User ID=USER ID;Password=PASSWORD;Pooling=true;CheckConnectionOnOpen=true;")

    connection.Open()

    ... Run Stored Procedure ...

    connection.Close()

End Using
```

Comment: What message is needing the response? Fix the cause of the message.

Comment: You probably have to open a new connection altogether.  You have `Pooling=true` (and `CheckConnectionOnOpen=true`), which is probably causing the connection objects to be cached (as they're usually expensive to create).  What's the size of your connection pool?  Increasing that may alleviate the problem for now.  Long term, though, it's best to figure out what's causing long locks/waits, and remove/shorten them.

Answer (score 0):

What version of client access do you have installed on the server? If it is 6, you will need to install the latest service pack on top and this should fix the issue.

Comment: V7R1M0. Is there a service pack we need on top of this? Do you have a link to any documentation on this issue?

Comment: We need to know what service level you're at before knowing if there's a later one. V7R1 is the version/release. A service pack probably won't help; MSGW implies a problem in your usage or application that needs to be fixed. A new connection has a good chance of simply getting the same status so you'll have multiple jobs in the same state.